# Parsing string values in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am importing sql into my Access database and am working on parsing the data into the correct tables and fields. Again I turn to you gurus to assist in a problem

One of the fields that is imported has comma separated values that need to be separated.there are anywhere from one to 10 possible values in the string.

```
 PHO,Rosgen,NRCS,EMAP,T-DL,YSI-DL
```

I have figured out that if I make all of the values the same length (say 4 characters) I can get the 1st, last and 1st after the comma to parse but cannot seem to get the middle values extracted correctly.

```
SELECT Left([FieldForms],InStr([FieldForms],",")-1) AS DEQ_SampleTypeID
FROM tblSiteVisit
UNION ALL
SELECT Mid([FieldForms],InStr([FieldForms],",")+1,4) AS DEQ_SampleTypeID
FROM tblSiteVisit
UNION ALL
SELECT Mid([FieldForms], 11, 4) AS DEQ_SampleTypeID
FROM tblSiteVisit
UNION ALL
SELECT Mid([FieldForms], 16, 4) AS DEQ_SampleTypeID
FROM tblSiteVisit
UNION ALL
SELECT Mid([FieldForms], 21, 4) AS DEQ_SampleTypeID
FROM tblSiteVisit
UNION ALL
SELECT Mid([FieldForms],InStrRev([FieldForms],",")-4,4) AS DEQ_SampleTypeID
FROM tblSiteVisit
UNION ALL
SELECT Right([FieldForms],InStr([FieldForms],",")-1) AS DEQ_SampleTypeID
FROM tblSiteVisit
```

If I use the InStrRev or the Right Function I get repeats if there are fewer than the maximum also using the Mid functions results in empty rows.

Is there a way to parse out a string like this and only get results from the string

Comment: This would be easier IMO with an Access VBA procedure instead of a query.  Would that be a suitable option for you?

Comment: Anything that would work is an option

Comment: `Split(FieldForms, ",")` will give you a string array.  Add a row to your destination table for each item in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following functions into a Module:

```
   Function CountCSWords (ByVal S) As Integer
  ' Counts the words in a string that are separated by commas.

  Dim WC As Integer, Pos As Integer
     If VarType(S) <> 8 Or Len(S) = 0 Then
       CountCSWords = 0
       Exit Function
     End If
     WC = 1
     Pos = InStr(S, ",")
     Do While Pos > 0
       WC = WC + 1
       Pos = InStr(Pos + 1, S, ",")
     Loop
     CountCSWords = WC
  End Function

  Function GetCSWord (ByVal S, Indx As Integer)
  ' Returns the nth word in a specific field.

  Dim WC As Integer, Count As Integer, SPos As Integer, EPos As Integer
     WC = CountCSWords(S)
     If Indx < 1 Or Indx > WC Then
       GetCSWord = Null
       Exit Function
     End If
     Count = 1
     SPos = 1
     For Count = 2 To Indx
       SPos = InStr(SPos, S, ",") + 1
     Next Count
     EPos = InStr(SPos, S, ",") - 1
     If EPos <= 0 Then EPos = Len(S)
     GetCSWord = Trim(Mid(S, SPos, EPos - SPos + 1))
  End Function
```

Then, put a field in your query like this:

```
MyFirstField: GetCSWord([FieldForms],1)
```

Put another one in like this:

```
MySecondField: GetCSWord([FieldForms],2)
```

Etc... for as many as you need.

Comment: It seems to me that using the [Split()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/split-function-HA001228911.aspx) function could simplify this code quite a bit.

Comment: Couldn't figure out how to do that in a query.  Split() would create an array.  If you can figure it out, post it!

Comment: Not the worlds best at VBA...I created the module and the query but it isn't working, I seem to have messed up somewhere. I get an error about an invalid parentheses. Can you give me the query in sql?

Comment: Try this:  SELECT GetCSWord([FieldForms],1) as MyFirstField, 
GetCSWord([FieldForms],2) as MySecondField FROM tblSiteVisit.  That is, assuming the name of the field with the comma separated values is "FieldForms".  If not, change the SQL code accordingly.  That should give you a query with the first 2 values in your field.  If ti works, just repeat accordingly.  If it doesn't, then let me know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

This VBA code reads text values from *FieldForms* in *tblSiteVisit*, splits that text into substrings, and then stores each of the substrings in *DEQ_SampleTypeID* in a new row added to *tblDestination*.

```vb
Dim astrItems() As String
Dim db As DAO.database
Dim i As Long
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strInsert As String

strInsert = "INSERT INTO tblDestination (DEQ_SampleTypeID)" & vbCrLf & _
    "VALUES ([array_item]);"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tblSiteVisit", dbOpenTable, dbOpenSnapshot)
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strInsert)
Do While Not rs.EOF
    astrItems = Split(rs!FieldForms, ",")
    For i = 0 To UBound(astrItems)
        qdf.Parameters("array_item") = astrItems(i)
        qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set qdf = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure (always leave that last 1%...) that this will just insert a new record into a table for each comma separated value.  Even though the OP posted a UNION ALL SQL string, his text states he's looking for a way to get each CSV broken out, which tells me he wants them separated into individual **fields**.  Which makes much more sense than creating new **records** for each value.